# Split tracking participants inaccurately

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ab-testing

I recently started using [Split](https://github.com/andrew/split/wiki) gem for A/B testing in production, and it appears that it's not counting participants accurately. The dashboard shows 7700 participants over a very short time period, whereas Google Analytics counts less than 400 actual uniques and 2000 pageviews over that same period.

How can I ensure that only actual people are counted, and that crawlers/bots are excluded? These results are *wildly* inaccurate.

[image: Example from Split dashboard]

Comment: Having the same issue, with the same relations: having about 300 participants in Split gem, but Google Analytics counting only 20 uniques.

Answer (score 1):

Split will include all bot traffic as it's on your server. Depending on what version of GA you're using you should either set a custom dimension (analytics.js) or custom variable (ga.js) based on the split test and then do your GA analysis there.

```
<script>
window.datalayer = window.datalayer || {};
window.datalayer.testing = '<%= @split_test_result %>'
</script>

<script>
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXX-X']);
if (window.datalayer && window.datalayer.testing){
    _gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 5, 'Testing', window.datalayer.testing, 3]);
}
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
</script>
```

Or it looks like he already has a gem going you can use: https://github.com/andrew/split-analytics